# websocket and ActiveMQ

Tags: spring-jms, spring-websocket

I have a program that send messages using `JmsTemplate` as below

```
@Override
    public void send(SonusCDR cdr) {
        jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(true);
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("cdrserver/calls/" + cdr.getIncomingCallingNumber() , new BaseCDRMessage(cdr));
    }
```

on another web site (hosting inside tomcat) i am trying to receive the message directly through STOMP

```
@Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic", "/queue")
                .setRelayHost("192.168.70.149")
                .setRelayPort(61613);
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("panel");

    }
```

now when i try to connect from HTML to `/topic/cdrserver/calls/121` , i do receive the message but with empty body

I think the problem is that message is not serialized before being sent to ActiveMQ . What is the best way to overcome this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i have done to fix the serialization issue but i am not sure it is the recommended way , may be serializing the message from the beginning is better but for now this is my solution

```
@JmsListener(destination = "cdrserver/calls")
public void receiveMessage1(BaseCDRMessage cdrMessage) {
    cdrMonitorService.sendCDR(cdrMessage);
}


@Override
public void sendCDR(BaseCDRMessage cdrMessage) {
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/panel/calls/" + cdrMessage.getIncomingCallingNumber(),cdrMessage);
}
```